# How to solve $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{x^2-x\sin(x)} e^{-i y x} dx$

Tags: fourier-transform

How to solve this Fourier Transform? It would be very helpful even if you can just share your thoughts on the approach to such problems. It is fine if the answer has diracdelta (or its derivatives) and similar such "functions".

$FT(\sqrt{x^2-x\sin(x)}) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{x^2-x\sin(x)} e^{-i y x} dx$

**Edit**: I changed the problem as per my brief exchange with Eric (in comments section). This is to retain focus on the main issue, which is approaching FT of functions raised to fractional powers (square root in my example).

Comment: That’s not defined for negative $x$…

Comment: This is going to be pretty difficult to do distributionally. @Eric hit one issue to that point. Another is how complicated your integrand is. Why do you expect this to have a nice Fourier transform? Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @Eric, can you comment if I remove the negative part by changing the problem to $\sqrt{x^2-x sin(x)}$

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I was looking at deconvolution problems in general and was trying to see how these are dealt with in general. The FT without the sqare root is trivial obviously and a square root in one domain is deconvolution (of convolution of that into some unknown function) in FT domain. Sorry I don't have a super concrete goal in mind. Just inviting thoughts and approaches to such problems as a way of learning.

Comment: Hmm interesting thought process. I think you'll find that distributional Fourier transforms are pretty difficult with even simple examples, much more so for more complicated examples like this one. See if you can simplify the problem some by using functions that have cute substitutions (like $\sqrt{\tan^2(x) + 1} = |\sec(x)|$ or some such) first. Deconvolution/deblurring is a *very* deep and difficult topic with functions in $L^1$ and $L^2$. It'll be worse in the distributional setting.